# Why PipelineDotRenderer in apache beam is throwing a npe?

Tags: streaming, pipeline, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm building a pipeline and I want to see the dot representation of it, I'm using this

```
public class PlotDAG extends PTransform<PCollection<KV<Long, ElasticRow>>, PCollection<KV<Long, ElasticRow>>> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(PlotDAG.class);

    public static PlotDAG of() {
        return new PlotDAG();
    }

    @Override
    public PCollection<KV<Long, ElasticRow>> expand(PCollection<KV<Long, ElasticRow>> input) {
        final String dotString = PipelineDotRenderer.toDotString(PDone.in(input.getPipeline()).getPipeline());
        LOG.info(dotString);
        return input;
    }
}
```

but the method throws an error

```
[INFO] 2022-11-09 10:14:15.307 DAGOrchestrator - PlotDAG
[INFO] 2022-11-09 10:14:15.307 DAGOrchestrator - Applying transformation PlotDAG
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Outputs for non-root node PlotDAG are null
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:980)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:597)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$500(TransformHierarchy.java:240)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:214)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:469)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.construction.renderer.PipelineDotRenderer.toDotString(PipelineDotRenderer.java:37)
    at dev.donhk.transform.PlotDAG.expand(PlotDAG.java:23)
    at dev.donhk.transform.PlotDAG.expand(PlotDAG.java:13)
```

I have used this method in another project and I did not have any problem but I'm not sure if this is because in this code the pipeline does not have a PDone at the end

How can I "temporarily end the pipeline" to prevent having null Outputs for non-root nodes?
What concept I have missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're getting this error because you're trying to walk the pipeline before PlotDAG's expand method has finished (hence it has no outputs (yet)). (I'm also not sure what the `PDone.in(input.getPipeline()).getPipeline()` logic is trying to accomplish.

I would suggest not trying to inspect the pipeline itself from within a PTransform. Instead of a PlotDAG  transform, pass the pipeline itself to `PipelineDotRenderer.toDotString` when you're done constructing it.

Coincidentally, you might be interested in https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/24037 .